# Check if matching name is linked to blob in Azure

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

So I'm wanting to match specific names to blobs inside my container and for some reason, I'm unable to pass in specific names.

Here is the code:

```
public function blob_exists(string $name, string $prefix = '') : int
{
    $list_blobs_options = new ListBlobsOptions();
    $list_blobs_options->setPrefix($prefix . $name);
    $result = $this->connect()->listBlobs($this->container_name,
            $list_blobs_options);

    return count($result->getBlobs());
}
```

**Problem**:

Let's say I have a name `SMITHRA`, it's returning a `count: 1` because it found the `SMITHRAC` name in the container. Is there a way that I can make the `$name` be specific matches and not just pull in the prefix?

So let's say I do this:

`var_dump($azure->blob_exists('SMITHRA', 'Big/'));` .. I get a value of 1 returned because it found `Big/SMITHRAC` in the container, I'd like to return only the matching `Big/SMITHRA`.

Comment: You can iterate through the returned results using `foreach` and compare blob names to ensure there's exact match. E.g. something like `$blobs = $result->getBlobs(); $match = false; foreach ($blobs as $blob) { if ($blob->name() === $string) { $match = true; break; } }`

Comment: I think you can directly use the name to get the blob to check if the blob exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if one blob exists with PHP, you can refer to the following code

```
$containerName ='';
$name=""
$blobClient = BlobRestProxy::createBlobService($connectionString);
try {
       
        $getBlobResult = $blobClient->getBlob($containerName, $name);
} catch (ServiceException $e) {
        $code = $e->getCode();
        if($code==404){
             echo "The specified blob does not exist.";
        }
}
```